# UIViewController Release in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am Using 5 pages in my project..
Here i can navigate pages 1 to 5 one by one using presentModelViewController..
How to release in between pages such as 2,3,4 when i navigate from page 5 to page 1..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

To pop directly to root view controller use:

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

In order to pop back to a specific controller use this code:

```
    NSArray *viewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[viewController objectAtIndex:1]  animated:YES];
```

Here **objectAtIndex** will be your required viewVController.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use pushViewController instead of presentModalViewController to push multiple views onto the nav controller stack. When you want to go back to the root call popToRootViewControllerAnimated and your UINavigationController will release all of the views that are no longer on the view stack.

Comment: Then what to doo when i want to navigate to 5th to 2nd page.